# Issue with Strava API

Tags: php

I am trying to get a list of my activities using cURL I can get the list of my clubs ok. Can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong

I am having an issue when using the request. $ http GET "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/{id}?include_all_efforts=" "Authorization: Bearer [[token]]"

```
I cam getting an error 



string(95) "{"message":"Record Not Found","errors": 
[{"resource":"Activity","field":"id","code":"invalid"}]}"


**I have tried the following** 


    $num = "2149016538";
    $int = (int)$num;
   // $url = 'https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/clubs';
    $url = 'https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/{'.$int.'}?include_all_efforts=true';

**No success**

**I have also tried this** 

       $num = "2149016538";
    $int = (int)$num;
   // $url = 'https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/clubs';
     $url = 'https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/?id='.$int.'?include_all_efforts=true';



    $authorization = "Authorization: Bearer 23232323";
    $num = "2149016538";
    $int = (int)$num;
   // $url = 'https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/clubs';
    $url = 'https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/{'.$int.'}?include_all_efforts=true';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

   // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    var_dump($result);
    curl_close($ch);
    json_decode($result);
```

Comment: Hi, according to documentation of Strava, you don't need curly braces around id

Comment: I have tried with /?id=1234 and it doesnt work

Comment: Try just https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/1234

Comment: I get this error string(123) "{"message":"Authorization Error","errors":[{"resource":"AccessToken","field":"activity:read_permission","code":"missing"}]}"

Comment: Are you sure you are using right activity id and right access token?

Comment: I am using this to request access <a href="https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?scope=read,activity:read_all,profile:read_all,read_all&client_id=32640&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/strava-call-back.php&approval_prompt=force">Get info</a>